# Getting URL of next page

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, http-redirect

Is it possible to get the URL of the next page when leaving the current page in C#?

On my current page I would like to capture the url of the next page before the next page loads. I'm not sure where to start for this...or in which method on my page I would place this logic (such as page_load, buttonClick etc.)

Comment: Is this Asp.net? How is the user going to next page? Hyperlink? Form Post? Redirect?

Comment: yes this is ASP.NET. The user would be redirecting to another page

Comment: If the user action sends your page back to the server before loading the new page, you should know where it is heading. Check for `Response.Redirect`

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to solve. What's the issue you're trying to address?

Comment: How will the user redirect? Redirects happen in code. So there should be some user action which would invoke the redirect code. In any case, can you not capture the URL that the control is being redirected to?

Comment: Currently I have a page called add_actions.aspx. On this page the user adds some information. However a notification is not sent until the user hits the SUBMIT button and the records are updated in the database. I would like for there to be some validation to ensure that the SUBMIT button is actually clicked before the user redirects away from the current page....I would like to get the URL of the next page and compare it to the current page and then do my validations. However I don't know how to get the URL of the next page request...

Comment: I realized that I can use Response.IsResponseBeingRedirected to see if the page is being redirected. My problem is where on the current page can I put that method to do that check when it is leaving the current page.

Comment: So the user isn't "redirecting", the user is navigating to another page (either by clicking a hyperlink, typing in another url) and you want to warn the user if he hasn't submitted yet?

Comment: @comecme yes that's the aim

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that it's possible to "capture the url of the next page", but you can get the current request as soon as possible. Use [`Global.asax`](http://aspalliance.com/1114_Understanding_the_Globalasax_file.all) therefore:

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext context = base.Context;
        HttpResponse response = context.Response;
        HttpRequest request = context.Request;
        var url = request.RawUrl;
        // and many other properties ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're doing paging through query strings and your current page is:

```
url.com/default.aspx?page=1
```

Then getting the next page URL would just be incrementing the page query string, so:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrempty(Request.QueryString["page"]) {
  int nextPageNumber = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["page"] + 1; 
  string nextPageUrl = String.Format("url.com/default.aspx?page={0}, nextPageNumber);
}
```

Ideally you would use [UriBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.aspx) to reconstruct the domain and not hard code it as I have in the String.Format method. I did this just for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

CodeProject has a project for [saving change on close or exiting page](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20260/Save-Changes-on-Close-of-Browser-or-When-Exiting-t) which might be helpful to you.