# How to detect if the user is closing the browser OR navigate on other website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, dom-events

I want to implement session handling in the way that if the user closes the browser or tab all sessions are expired/destroyed. But I want to keep all the sessions if the user is navigating to another website.
How can I do this in Nextjs?

Answer (score -2):

You can use an event listener for an `unload` event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unload_event

But given that you're in React/Next.js land, you'll likely want to hook up that listener inside a `useEffect` hook, and if you're going to do that ...

... you can simply skip the event listener entirely, and use the `return` value of the `useEffect` as your "unload" handler.

As explained here (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) when you `return` a function from inside a `useEffect`, that function gets called when the component is removed from the page.

If you add the code you want to trigger "onUnload" into the returned function from a `useEffect` on your "App" component, this will have the same effect as using an unload event listener.

```
// App.js
import { useEffect}, React from 'react'

App = () => {
   useEffect(() => {
       return () => {
         // add code to trigger when the user leaves here
       }
   })
}
```

Comment: But how can I decide if the tab is closing or navigating to another website? According to my knowledge window.onload will run on both times (navigate/close)

Comment: As noted in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711262/getting-url-of-next-page it is not possible for your page to know where the user is going when they leave.

Comment: Actually, I take that back; if you use Google Analytics (https://www.orbitmedia.com/blog/whered-they-go-track-every-exit-click-using-google-tag-manager-in-10-steps/) it seems you can differentiate.  Unfortunately I'm not sure how GA is accomplishing that.